# Как сделать так, чтобы не записывалось новое значение в MySQL phpMyAdmin если в первом уже есть такие значения только записанные в разные поля

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в таблицу вставляются значения first_code и second_code, но они должны быть уникальны я написал скрипт который должен был проверять это:

```
public function isChatInDatabase($code1, $code2){
        $stmt = $this -> con -> prepare("SELECT id FROM chats WHERE (first_code = ? and second_code = ?) or (second_code = ? and first_code = ?)");
        $stmt -> bind_param("ssss", $code1,$code2, $code1, $code2);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        if ($stmt -> num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

но всё равно добавляется такое же значение. Я в PHP совсем недавно, а конкретнее он мне только для базы данных нужен. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

[image: фото из базы данных]

У одного кода может быть несколько других кодов и даже он сам:
[image: Пример из базы данных]

Мне нужно именно проверять, есть ли определённый код в поле first_code и у него есть второй код в поле second_code

Comment: Индекс UNIQUE отменили разве? php тут причем)

Comment: Ну так я и в SQL новенький. Я просто делаю проект и под него всё учу) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хорошо что вы не хирургом решили попрактиковаться) сначала вырезая сердце у пациента, а потом читая как нужно правильно

Comment: ахах я просто делаю школьный проект, там уж точно никто не станет проверять мои знания, главное чтобы работало

Comment: https://html5css.ru/sql/sql_unique.php тут можно почитать про индексы в mysql

Comment: Спасибо, но я забыл уточнить кое что

Answer (score -1):

Я нашёл решение своей проблемы:

```
public function func($code1, $code2){
        $stmt = $this -> con -> prepare("SELECT id FROM chats WHERE (first_code = ? and second_code = ?)");
        $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $code1,$code2);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        if ($stmt -> num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            $stmt = $this -> con -> prepare("SELECT id FROM chats WHERE (first_code = ? and second_code = ?)");
            $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $code2,$code1);
            $stmt -> execute();
            $stmt -> store_result();
            if ($stmt -> num_rows() == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Теперь всё работает как надо.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM chats WHERE (first_code = ? and second_code = ?) OR (first_code = ? and second_code = ?)`, `$stmt->execute([$code1, $code2, $code2, $code1]);` А, вообще, вам уже написали, зачем эти костыли если есть unique индекс...